# How can I get a list of the 21 Steam games that are not available on Windows?

Tags: steam, windows

(In this post I use the word "game" to mean anything in the Steam store, even it's not a game per se.)

Earlier today I was curious what percentage of Steam games are not available on Windows, so I used a [blank search](https://store.steampowered.com/search/?term=) to find the total number of Steam games (currently 85,828) and then [narrowed by OS](https://store.steampowered.com/search/?os=win) to find the number available on Windows (currently 85,807). So approximately 0.024% of Steam games are not available on Windows.

How can I find a list of these 21 rare games?

Answer (score 3):

[SteamDB](https://steamdb.info/) supports this, somewhat. One of the parameters in its "instant search" is "Platforms."

If you do a search for Windows, and then add a `-` before "Windows" in your address bar, you can run a search excluding titles supporting Windows.

This by itself is not enough, since it seems there are some games that list no supported systems, and yet the Steam page shows it's available for Windows. If you narrow this down by adding one of the other platforms, you can get, for example, [a list of games on Steam that are only available on macOS](https://steamdb.info/instantsearch/?refinementList%5BappType%5D%5B0%5D=Game&refinementList%5Boslist%5D%5B0%5D=-Windows).

Comment: Oh interesting, I didn't know about SteamDB, thanks! So using [this query](https://steamdb.info/instantsearch/?refinementList%5Boslist%5D%5B0%5D=-Windows&refinementList%5Boslist%5D%5B1%5D=macOS&refinementList%5Boslist%5D%5B2%5D=Linux) I see one game and two DLC's; am I using it correctly, or is there another way to see the full list of 21?

Comment: @SamEstep the platform list is a conjunction -- that's searching for "Not Windows AND Mac AND Linux". Unfortunately you'd have to go toggle each of the platforms in order, and then remove those that are double-counted from being available on multiple platforms; I haven't found a better way to do this so far.